# Close console window after execution

Tags: c#, process

I am opening a console program from a c# code using the below code

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"exepath");
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("b{0} {1} {2}", i, var1, var2);
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

This results in opening a new console window and the execution of code from the console . But i noticed that this console window is not closing once the execution is completed . The Program.cs  of the opened console program is like this only

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.write("Executing....");          
        if (args == null || args.Length==0)
        {
            Console.write("No parameters....");
        }
        else
        {
            string batch = args[0];
            int offset = Convert.ToInt16(args[1]);
            int limit = Convert.ToInt16(args[2]);
            Console.write("Found few parameters....");                 
            ExecuteAFunction(offset, limit);

        }
         Console.write("End");
    }
```

There is no Console.ReadLine or wait for input code is written here. So how can i make sure that the window opened by code Process.Start will be closed after the completion of execution

Comment: you can always use `Environment.Exit(0)` in your code....

Comment: Is `ExecuteAFunction` still executing?

Comment: @MickyD ExecuteAFunction  completed the execution and i can see log "End" in console.

Comment: Is there anything else you aren't showing?  The window should just close by itself assuming your `Main` has completed

Comment: @MickyD Yes that is what i am also thinking. I have to cross check in deep now .

Answer (score 0):

you either need to wait for process to complete like below

```
Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "CMD.EXE";
//command may be on command window 
p.Start(psi);
p.WaitForExit(); //wait for exit
```

or should close

```
Process myProcess = Process.Start(psi); 
//close it 
myProcess.CloseMainWindow(); 
myProcess.Close(); 

//or kill process 
myProcess.Kill();
```

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to explicitly close a console window from a _fire-and-forget_ process

Comment: @MickyD - am not sure i got question correctly but answering on this line in question "There is no Console.ReadLine or wait for input code is written here. So how can i make sure that the window opened by code Process.Start will be closed after the completion of execution"

Comment: Any negative impact of using  Environment.Exit(0) as suggested by one

Comment: @JibinMathew - that will close you current application i.e. .net application but i doubt that it will close your command process window